# Will Ubuntu 20.04 work on a mid 2013 Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook

Just realized my Macbook just became obsolete a few months ago. I noticed my processor (1.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5) isn't as fast as the 2 GHz dual core processor listed on Ubuntu's installation page. Would it still work on this machine, just slowly? Thanks.

Comment: Why not try it on your actual hardware - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install  (Even if Ubuntu isn't *super* fast, other lighter *flavors* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) can provide faster performance (the *try* works for *flavors* too)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/1438484) See also [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/1438484)